# Deriving the variance of the Poisson distribution - making an error somewhere?

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value, variance, poisson-distribution

Having issues deriving the $E[X^2]$ term.

1. Can someone explain lines 5 to 6 here for me? I don't understand how they get $\lambda^2$ in the first term. Seemingly then $n= \lambda$? Which doesn't make sense to me. I'm not sure if they made an error.

[Deriving E[X^2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqgum.png)

Lines I don't get: [image]

2. I've tried deriving $E[X^2]$ myself but am making an error somewhere as I lose the $\lambda$ term, maybe in the change of the sum?:

$$\begin{align}E[X^2] &= \sum_{n \in X} n^2P(X=n)\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^2 \frac{\lambda^n}{n!}e^{-\lambda} \\ 
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty n^2 \frac{\lambda^n}{n!} \bigg(\frac{-\lambda^n}{n!}\bigg) \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2 \frac{\lambda^n}{n(n-1)!} \bigg(\frac{-\lambda^n}{n(n-1)!}\bigg) \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\lambda^n}{(n-1)!} \bigg(\frac{-\lambda^n}{(n-1)!}\bigg) \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\lambda^{n+1}}{n!} \bigg(\frac{-\lambda^{n+1}}{n!}\bigg) \\
&= \lambda^2 \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{ \lambda^{n}}{n!} \bigg(\frac{-\lambda^{n}}{n!}\bigg)\\
&= \lambda^2 e^\lambda e^{-\lambda}\\
& = \lambda^2 \\
\end{align}$$

Using:

$$ e^x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The $\lambda^2$ come from the following
   \begin{align}
   \sum_{n=0}^\infty n\frac{\lambda^{n+1}}{n!}e^{-\lambda}&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\frac{\lambda^{n+1}}{n!}e^{-\lambda}&\mbox{ the term for }n=0\mbox{ vanishes}\\
   &=\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{\lambda^{n+1}}{(n-1)!}e^{-\lambda}&\\
   &=\sum_{\ell=0}^\infty \frac{\lambda^{\ell+2}}{\ell!}e^{-\lambda}&\mbox{doing the substitution }\ell=n-1
   \end{align}
   then we conclude using $\sum_{\ell=0}^\infty \frac{\lambda^{\ell+2}}{\ell!}=\lambda^2\sum_{\ell=0}^\infty \frac{\lambda^{\ell}}{\ell!}=\lambda^2 e^{\lambda}$.
2. In your attempt, you seem to use (at the third equal sign) that if $b=\sum_{n\geqslant 0}b_n$, then $\sum_{n\geqslant 0}a_nb=\sum_{n\geqslant 0}a_nb_n$ which is not true in general.

Comment: Awesome thanks, not enough rep to upvote yet :)

Comment: Thanks! Welcome to Math Stgack Exchange by the way!